# listing downloaded files' names numerically vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a project, that downloads HTML files and are saved with names 0.html to 10.html.. these files are then processed to extract links.. I want these files to be processed one by one in order from 0 to 10. Since I am downloading multiple files simultaneously, so the files downloaded are not in order like first 0 is downloaded then 2,6,3,1 and so on..

so, in order to achieve the order processing I can't think of any way other than finding a way to list downloaded files in order. lets say if 2 is downloaded before 1, 2 shall be added to list right after 1 is downloaded and listed..

Or if anyone can suggest any other way..

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can do. First create a SortedDictionary object to store the file name with Integer key, Maybe you can put status in this key value list. So Value is to tell if key name file is downloaded or still in queue. IF downloaded you can parse it or wait.  Another way is use some Database and sort them before you do the job. In nutshell you just have to sort your List. I think Linq can do that as well provided you use Integer datatype, string will fetch 10 before 2 always.

Comment: well, that process thing, that is done through backgroundworker. since, there may be 1000+ pages, so in order to save the time, i want them to be processed at the same time.. so I guess sorting the list will be of no use..

Comment: You can still use that method, as I said.. make an Public List. update the Index status as "Processing", "Downloading" and then create a new thread that parse this array, if status is "ready for process" process file otherwise move on, and keep your loop on list going on until all items are processed.

Comment: please post your code and someone will surely help and me too :).